# How to fetch object names while parsing JSON

Tags: jquery, json, object, each

Say my json looks like this :

```
{
    "Heading1":{"internal 1":[0,0,0,1],"internal 2":[0,0,0,0]},
    "Heading2":{"internal 1":[0,0,0,0],"internal 2":[0,0,0,0]}
}
```

I wrote the following jquery function

```
$.each(jsonData, function(index, data){
        console.log(data);
    });
```

But this only gives me the separate objects as such:

```
{"internal 1":[0,0,0,1],"internal 2":[0,0,0,0]}
```

and

```
{"internal 1":[0,0,0,0],"internal 2":[0,0,0,0]}
```

But how do i fetch the "`Heading`" (i.e the object name) for each ? is there an inbulit attribute? like say data.name or data.id or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$.each`, the `index` property you defined is actually the key:

```
$.each(jsonData, function(key, value){
    console.log(key) //Heading1
})
```

Or, `for in`

```
for (var key in jsonData) {
    console.log(key) //Heading1
    console.log(jsonData[key]) //{"internal 1":[0,0,0,1],"internal 2":[0,0,0,0]}
}
```